# Valid time zones in lubridate

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

A quick google search seems to get me nowhere. What are valid time zones in lubridate's `tz` option? In particular, am looking for Brasilia's time zone. Thanks!

```
library(lubridate)
dts <- c("6-3-1995 12:01:01","29-3-1995 23:01:01","29-3-1995 20:01:01")
dmy_hms(dts)               # locale's tz default
dmy_hms(dts, tz = "chile") # Chilean time (has one time zone only)
```

Comment: Take a search through `OlsonNames()` - e.g.: `grep("Brazil",OlsonNames(),value=TRUE)`

Comment: Brilliant @thelatemail! This narrows down the options. I presume that "Brazil/East" is the correct one...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take a search through the `OlsonNames()` in the standard `base` R package, which provides a list of all the valid timezones on the host system. e.g.:

```
grep("Brazil", OlsonNames(), value=TRUE)
```

...provides four possible results for Brazil.

Comment: I am a Brazilian and I find this particularly trick... now it 11:40 pm, and I am in the Brazil/East region, and when run lubridate's now(tz = "Brazil/East") it is one hour ahead, in the next day.

 "2021-02-15 00:41:27 -02"

Comment: I think it could be related to daylight saving time, a witch no longer exists in Brazil anymore.

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues - if you know how many hours +/- from GMT/UTC you are in your current location, you can use that timezone without any daylight savings consideration. E.g. try `now(tz="Etc/GMT+3")` maybe?

Comment: That is correct and helpful. I also found other Brazilian cities in OlsonNames(), under "America/city" names. "America/Recife" is set to GMT -03.

Comment: `grep("America", OlsonNames(), value=TRUE)`

Comment: If you just want to show it in the timezone of your system, you can use `tz = Sys.timezone()`.

Comment: Neat. Was looking for this. Immense help