# Digging into R package: Time Zones in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I started playing with the [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package in R. I noticed that `now(tzone="EST")` computed as:

```
[1] "2015-08-25 13:01:08 EST"
```

while `now(tzone="PST")` resulted in warning:

```
[1] "2015-08-25 18:02:16 GMT"
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'PST'
```

**So what are the *known* timezones?** [Valid Timezones in Lubridate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784310/valid-time-zones-in-lubridate) has an answer. But I'd like to see how I can answer this for myself (i.e., by digging through the package itself). I look at the `now()` function:

```
> now
function (tzone = "") 
with_tz(Sys.time(), tzone)
<environment: namespace:lubridate>
```

So then I look at the `with_tz` function:

```
> with_tz
function (time, tzone = "") 
{
    check_tz(tzone)
    if (is.POSIXlt(time)) 
        new <- as.POSIXct(time)
    else new <- time
    attr(new, "tzone") <- tzone
    reclass_date(new, time)
}
<environment: namespace:lubridate>
>
```

So then I check the `check_tz` function:

```
> check_tz
Error: object 'check_tz' not found
```

Not there. I search my local `lubridate` R library files for `check_tz`. I don't find anything. I do a Google Search and find [this GitHub page](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/R/time-zones.r). There it is! It appears that `olson_time_zones()` lists the *known* time zones. (**UPDATE: `olson_time_zones()` only returns a subset of the available time zones. See my comments below for more details.**) In particular,

```
> now(tzone="America/Los_Angeles")
[1] "2015-08-25 11:11:14 PDT"
```

**Q: How could I have answered my question about the list of known time zones if there weren't a nice file up on GitHub or post on StackOverflow with the answer? In other words, could I have found my answer by digging through my local `lubridate` library files?**

**Q: Is there a more general principle to digging through R packages which is worth pointing out?**

Comment: I, too, would like to know how to find this sort of thing out in R in general. In particular, here, is a particular lead on your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784310/valid-time-zones-in-lubridate

Comment: I think that *might* be happening because right now (late August) is always Pacific Daylight Time (PDT), and at this time during the year Pacific Standard Time (PST) does not exist.  Just a thought, no clue if it's correct or not.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I think it's even weirder that "EST" works at all since `stringr::str_subset(olson_time_zones(), "EST")` returns nothing. It appears `lubridate` also uses `OlsonNames()` for `tzone`. `str_subset(OlsonNames(), "EST")` returns "EST" and "EST5EDT". `str_subset(OlsonNames(), "PDT")` returns "PST8PDT".

Comment: A side-note here, that as of *lubridate 1.6* (Sept 2016), there is no longer `olson_time_zones` - '*`here` and `olson_time_zones` were deprecated in favor of `new` and base `OlsonNames` respectively.*'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a list of the timezones available by `lubridate` with:

```
lubridate::olson_time_zones()
```

This information is easily found by typing

```
??timezones
```

in the console. 
The link describing this function is the second entry in the list of the help page in my case:

[image]

Another possibility is to search the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf) of `lubridate` for "available time zones".

Comment: Certainly right that `??` ferrets out the right answer in this case.

Comment: I conceded too quickly that this worked. See my comments above in response to @RichardScriven. Time zones like "EST" and "PST8PDT" work in the `now()` function but are not returned by `olson_time_zones()`. So it appears `olson_time_zones()` only returns a subset of the available time zones.